# Google forms API : how to add custom css via code edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to custom a google form, want to hide google logo and back button on second section
i tried a function like this :

```
function myFunctioncss() {
function onOpen() {

var myLogoDeGoogle = document.querySelector(".freebirdFormviewerViewFooterImageContainer.freebirdFormviewerViewFooterPageBreak");
myLogoDeGoogle.style.display = "none";
var myBoutonRetour = document.querySelector(".quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonEl.quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonFlat.quantumWizButtonPaperbutton2El2.freebirdFormviewerViewNavigationNoSubmitButton");
myBoutonRetour.style.display = "none";
var myTitreTest = document.querySelector(".freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle.freebirdCustomFont");
myTitreTest.style.color = "red";
var myFond = document.querySelector(".freebirdFormviewerViewFormContent");
myFond.style.background = "green";

}
}
```

With a trigger on form open.
Not Errors but it does not change anything on the form.

All ideas will be welcome..

Comment: You can't do it.  `onOpen()` runs on the server.  `document.querySelector()` is a DOM method that can only run in the browser.  And the reserved function named `onOpen()` does not trigger when a Google Form is opened in "View" mode for user input.  It only runs when the Form is opened in Edit mode.  If you want functionality that a Google Form doesn't have, then you'll need to build your own input form.  You could create an Apps Script web app instead.  A Web App can be embedded in a site, just like a Google Form can.

Comment: This is definitely not a comment... you should rewrite it as an answer since I don't see what could make it more complete and pertinent.